# Installing hot water recirculating pump on a tankless water heater

Tags: pump, tankless

I'm trying to see if I can install a hot water recirculating pump on my current setup. My understanding is that the pump sits just before the hot water line that goes into the building, but since there is an expansion tank, I'm not sure if I can still do it.
Please see the photos [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH6JM.jpg).

Comment: Can? Yes. But it probably doesn't do what you think it does. In order for your plumbing to have quick access to hot water, your entire water system needs to be designed to recirculate. You need to outline what you think the recirculating pump would do and how it is setup relative to your existing plumbing.

Comment: Yes you can but...  Keep in mind that you're going to end up causing the WH to cycle on and off relatively quickly in order to keep the recirculating water hot.  You'll probably reduce the life of your heater.  Perhaps you might consider using more than one tankless heater so that there is always one close to the point of use.

Comment: @jwn20 I was gonna use a comfort valve and a pump like [this](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B009D7NJIG/?coliid=I2GG2H6KSWRZAM&colid=2B3M576OHNY15&psc=1&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it). Noritz, the manufacturer, said my particular model, EZTR40, cannot be used with such pumps as they won't create enough flow to start the heater. I am not sure how/where another tankless water heater closer to the master bedroom in the upper floor would be installed. Additionally, that will cost too much. As for the constant switching, I saw a YouTube video that suggested using a smart plug to start the pump on demand.

Answer (score 1):

I have added recirculating systems on a few occasions and even on a tankless. The pump , timer and cross over plumbing to use the cold water line as the recirculating line can be purchased in a kit usually under 200$ For the basic kit. With a tankless a pair of check valves are needed to create the pressure drop/ flow to fire the tankless. It can be done but in my opinion eliminates the advantage of a tankless. I usually suggest a point of use small tankless at the bathroom these smaller electric units are on demand like the main unit but will warm the water until the main supply of warm makes it Once the water makes it they can actually help to stabilize the water temp and there cost is about the same as a pump, timer and crossover kit. The difference is the point of use usually requires a 240v 30 amp circuit to be run for the unit. This would be my suggestion and it eliminates the warm water in the cold line. The advantage to the recirculating system is in cold areas with the timer adjusted properly the recirculating system keeps pipes from freezing as both the hot and cold are used.